# "Municipality of <municipality-name>" or "<municipality-name> Municipality"

Tags: usage, word-order, nouns, sentence-usage, formality

I was discussing with some people about which form is more correct regarding a Municipality, or other territory divisions.

For example, regarding to a map of the municipality, is it more correct to use:

- "Map of the Municipality of Lisbon"
- "Map of the Lisbon Municipality"
- "Lisbon Municipality Map"

Or are all of them correct?
Which one would be used in a formal/informal context?

Couldn't find much about it online, besides example usages of the forms.

Comment: I spent weeks and weeks on a text re Madeira, which is very confusing with all the different levels of administrative areas some of which have the same name as another level.  First of all, I'd say city and not municipality here. Lisbon City Map. Unless, there is specific reason (history etc.), we would just say city. Why do you feel it necessary to use the word municipality, which in Portuguese is concelho or município.

Answer (score 1):

The first two

> "Map of the Municipality of Lisbon"
> "Map of the Lisbon Municipality"

Are more or less exchangeable

> "Lisbon Municipality Map"

sounds more informal. If you actually bought a paper object it might be labelled like that to save space on the cover.

Comment: In English it seems common to say "the country of Germany" rather than "Germany country", but "Berlin city" sounds fine. I'm not sure there's a general rule for all types of area.